# Save method not working in Django as expected

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

**Purpose:**
I am trying to setup a small local network monitor with basic UI that pings all the devices enlisted in the db and updates the status.

**Problem:**
save() method is not updating the DB.

**My Model:**

```
class Device(models.Model):
    dev_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dev_ip = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dev_name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('device-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**Function I wrote to ping the device and update DB:**

```
import platform
import subprocess
from netmon.models import Device
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=60)
def start_monitor():
    devices = Device.objects.all()
    print(">>>>>>>>>>> In Start_monitor <<<<<<<<<<<")
    for device in devices:
        if (ping(device.dev_ip)):
            device.status = "Alive"
        else:
            device.status = "Dead"
        device.save(update_fields=["dev_status"])
```

I am a Django beginner, please let me know if you need any more details. All answers are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you update the `dev_status` field, you need to assign the status to `device.dev_status`, not <s>`device.status`</s>:

```
@background(schedule=60)
def start_monitor():
    devices = Device.objects.all()
    print('>>>>>>>>>>> In Start_monitor <<<<<<<<<<<')
    for device in devices:
        if (ping(device.dev_ip)):
            device.dev_status = 'Alive'  # ← update dev_status
        else:
            device.dev_status = 'Dead'  # ← update dev_status
        device.save(update_fields=['dev_status'])
```

Comment: Just noticed, my bad. Thank you